# Thread.join() is not working at expect in Dining Philosophers implementation

Tags: java, operating-system, synchronized, monitor, dining-philosopher

I have implemented the Dining Philosopher problem using Monitor (Synchronized) in Java.

The goal of this program is:

- Every philosopher should follow the workflow of think, get chopsticks, eat, put chopsticks (no race conditions).
- No Deadlock

I think this code seems to work fine but something is not right because it is run forever I tried to debug it and the debugging tool stop at this line philosopher[i].t.join(); but the program was not terminated.

Please help my identify the problem or show me how to fix it.
Thank you for your advice.

MyMonitor class:

```
class MyMonitor {
    private enum States {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING};
    private States[] state;

    public MyMonitor() {
        state = new States[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            state[i] = States.THINKING;
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is THINKING");
        }
    }

    private void test(int i) {
        if((state[(i+4)%5]!=States.EATING) && (state[i]==States.HUNGRY) && (state[(i+1)%5]!=States.EATING)) {
            state[i] = States.EATING;
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is EATING");
            notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pickup(int i) {
            state[i] = States.HUNGRY;
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is HUNGRY");      
            test(i);
            if (state[i] != States.EATING) {
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is WAITING");
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }

    public synchronized void putdown(int i) {
            state[i] = States.THINKING;
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is THINKING");
            test((i+4)%5);
            test((i+1)%5);
        }
    }
```

MyPhilosopher class:

```
class MyPhilosopher implements Runnable{
    private int myID;
    private int eatNum;
    private MyMonitor monitor;
    private Thread t;

    public MyPhilosopher(int myID, int eatNum, MyMonitor monitor) {
        this.myID = myID;
        this.eatNum = eatNum;
        this.monitor = monitor;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int count = 1;
        while(count <= eatNum ){
            monitor.pickup(myID);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            monitor.putdown(myID);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int eatNum = 10;

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("xxx");
        System.out.println("xxx");
        System.out.println("xxx");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Starting");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        MyMonitor monitor = new MyMonitor();
        MyPhilosopher[] philosopher = new MyPhilosopher[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            philosopher[i] = new MyPhilosopher(i, eatNum, monitor);
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                philosopher[i].t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Ended");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are in the debugger you can review all application threads. Every IDE has the possibility to display and switch between running threads. There's a big chance that you will find a deadlock then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have executed your code and it runs perfectly until two or more executions. In addition, you can decrease the sleep time, your code is correct but perfect until 4 pilosophers are waiting and one of them is eating. I don't like it. You are breaking out one coffman condition but i recomend you to use other implementations as by breaking hold and wait conditions. I mean, you can take both chopsticks or none, other implementation can be, even pilosophers take the chopsticks on the right and the odd pilosophers take the left one. Good Luck!

```
Philosopher 4 is THINKING
Philosopher 0 is EATING
Philosopher 3 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 3 is WAITING
Philosopher 1 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 1 is WAITING
Philosopher 2 is THINKING
Philosopher 3 is EATING
Philosopher 0 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is EATING
Philosopher 4 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 4 is WAITING
Philosopher 3 is THINKING
Philosopher 4 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 2 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 0 is WAITING
Philosopher 1 is THINKING
Philosopher 2 is EATING
Philosopher 4 is THINKING
Philosopher 0 is EATING
Philosopher 3 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 3 is WAITING
Philosopher 2 is THINKING
Philosopher 3 is EATING
Philosopher 1 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 1 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is EATING
Philosopher 4 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 4 is WAITING
Philosopher 3 is THINKING
Philosopher 4 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 2 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 0 is WAITING
Philosopher 1 is THINKING
Philosopher 2 is EATING
Philosopher 3 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 3 is WAITING
Philosopher 4 is THINKING
Philosopher 0 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is THINKING
Philosopher 3 is EATING
Philosopher 1 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 1 is WAITING
Philosopher 4 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 4 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 2 is WAITING
Philosopher 3 is THINKING
Philosopher 4 is EATING
Philosopher 1 is THINKING
Philosopher 2 is EATING
Philosopher 0 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 0 is WAITING
Philosopher 4 is THINKING
Philosopher 0 is EATING
Philosopher 3 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 3 is WAITING
Philosopher 2 is THINKING
Philosopher 3 is EATING
Philosopher 1 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 1 is WAITING
Philosopher 4 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 4 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 2 is WAITING
Philosopher 3 is THINKING
Philosopher 4 is EATING
Philosopher 0 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 0 is WAITING
Philosopher 1 is THINKING
Philosopher 2 is EATING
Philosopher 4 is THINKING
Philosopher 0 is EATING
Philosopher 2 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is HUNGRY
Philosopher 1 is WAITING
Philosopher 0 is THINKING
Philosopher 1 is EATING
Philosopher 1 is THINKING
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ended
```

But,i have checked that you have a deadlock in some special condition like this:
When all philosophers least one can eat and others are waiting. But i have changed your code in test by using synchronize in the header of the function, the if condition of the test() method by while and in  the method putdown() i have changed the notify by notifyAll();
The code is this:

```
class MyMonitor {
private enum States {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING};
private  States[] state;

public MyMonitor() {
    state = new States[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        state[i] = States.THINKING;
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is THINKING");
    }
}

private synchronized void test(int i) {
    while((state[(i+4)%5]!=States.EATING) && (state[i]==States.HUNGRY) && (state[(i+1)%5]!=States.EATING)) {
        state[i] = States.EATING;
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is EATING");
     //   notify();
    }
}

public synchronized void pickup(int i) {
        state[i] = States.HUNGRY;
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is HUNGRY");      
        test(i);
        if (state[i] != States.EATING) {
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is WAITING");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}

public synchronized void putdown(int i) {
        state[i] = States.THINKING;
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + i + " is THINKING");
        //test((i+4)%5);
        //test((i+1)%5);
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

I advise you to use one or more implementations and before thinking what coffman condition do you want to break. Good luck